# Hazelcast- Right place to register a Map Listener with a IMap

Tags: java, spring-boot, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have the following use-case

I have two Spring boot applications on two separate machines. One application is running with an embedded `hazelcast` and another application is connecting to the `hazelcast` running embedded.

I have two maps- one `IMap` and one MultiMap. I want to add an EntryEvictionListener
to the IMAP. WhaI I want to do is on the eviction of an entry from the `IMap`, go to the `MuliMap` and remove the corresponding entry from it.

I am using Spring java configuration. I wanted advice on where should I register the listener with the `IMap`. The class which implements EntryEvictionListener interface( which will be registered with `IMap`), it is a spring managed bean and also has other spring managed beans `autowired` inside of it.

I was planning to register the mapListener in the spring boot application which connects to the embedded `hazelcast` running in other spring boot application. I was planning to do it inside a `postconstruct` method, so it runs only once.

Is this a good approach?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT-

```
           Class CustomListener implements HazelcastInstanceAware,EntryEvictedListener{

   private HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance;

   @Override
   public void setHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance){

   this.hazelcastInstance=hazelcastInstance;

   }

   @Override
   public void entryEvicted(EntryEvent<String,String> event){

   // get multi map from hazelcast instance

   //remove value

  }


}
```

The above works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@indraneel-bende, please check this: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Distributed_Events/Distributed_Object_Events/Listening_for_Map_Events.html#page_Registering+Map+Listeners

If you use Hazelcast-Spring config, you can add the listener in the Hazelcast Config, could be XML config like in the doc or Java config, and that's it. Make sure that your `MapListener` is a Spring bean.

Comment: What if I am connecting to hazelcast ( the same hazelcast configuration this would lie in) in the spring managed bean because on eviction in IMap , I will be removing the corresponding value from MultiMap

Comment: @IndraneelBende, I couldn't understand what you mean. Can you please clarify?

Comment: My hazelcast is embedded in a Spring Boot Application.In the MapListener for a IMap which I will add in the Hazelcast Config , I will be connecting to the same embedded hazelcast instance to remove a value from a MultiMap, when a entry is evicted from an IMap. Is that okay? will that cause an issue?

Comment: @IndraneelBende `I will be connecting to the same embedded hazelcast instance`. When you say `connecting`, how are you connecting? Normally, you can just implement `HazelcastInstanceAware` in your listener & have access to `HazelcastInstance`. Then you can do whatever you want. Since it's a `Listener`, it won't block/affect anything

Comment: I will be using ClientConfig to create a connection.

Comment: You don't need to. You should have already a HazelcastInstance in that app' client or member. You can use it. If you share that class, I can help you.

Comment: You mean have a hazelcast instance by implementing the hazelcastInstanceAware interface in addition to the EntryEvictedListener interface.

Comment: Yes, that's how you can share the instance.

Comment: I don’t even need spring config anymore, just need to give the class name in hazelcast.xml

Comment: Btw the official docs say about haZelcastInstanceAware that it is used to get a hazelcastInstance reference when submitting a runnable/callable using hazelcast executor service. I am really not doing the above here.

Comment: OK, but you're connecting a cluster you already connected? Can you share your `EntryEvictionListener` so I can check, just to be sure.

Comment: It seems that its working. Yes you can use this approach safely. This Hazelcast instance is a client instance, i believe but actually it doesn’t matter. Also, since you’re using spring-boot, you can make your listener a Spring Bean & inject the hazelcast instance. That’s also possible.

Comment: I just added the name of class under the entry listener tag in map tag in hazelcast.xml.